# Kendo UI chart tooltip and redraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

My problem is as follows:

I want to have a scatterLine chart in Kendo UI where I can both show a tooltip and have a seriesHover effect.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lvzu9qh/2/

Comment out line 44:
`chart.redraw();` to see my issue. If the chart is redrawn, the tooltip is cleared. If the chart is not redrawn, I don't get my highlight effect.

How can I get both the highlight and tooltip? Alternate approaches to solve either problem are also accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work saving the previous id and changing color only when i change the serie:

```
var previousId = 0;
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    title: {
        text: "Line demo (Kendo UI v2014.3.1119)"
    },
    legend: {
        position: "bottom"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "scatterLine",
        width: 2,

    },
    series: [{
            name: "A",
            data: [[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]]
        },
        {
            name: "B",
            data: [[0,2], [1,3], [2,5]]
        },
        {
            name: "C",
            data: [[0,3], [1,5], [2,2]]
        }
    ],
    seriesHover : function(e) {

        var chart = e.sender;
        var idx = _.findIndex(chart.options.series, function (s) {
            return s === e.series;
        });
        if(previousId != idx)
            previousId = idx;
        else
            return;
        if (idx >= 0) {
            var thisSeries = chart.options.series[idx];
            // attach event to hovering over a series
            // On hover, set opacity to full and increase width
            // Decrease opacity and width on all other series
            _.each(chart.options.series, function (s) {
                s.width = 2;
                s.opacity = 0.4;
            });

            thisSeries.width = 4;
            thisSeries.opacity = 1;
             $("#chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();




        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "X: {0} Y: {1}"
    },
    transitions: false
});
```

Hope it helps.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lvzu9qh/4/

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I'll award the bounty as soon as I'm able.

Comment: Thanks! Id made it because the event fired several times in one second, so the chart was redrawing constantly (including the tooltip, i guess). So with that the charts only redraw when you change the series. Sorry the bad english.

Comment: Heh, that'd actually mean that in addition to the feature now working correctly, I also get a performance upgrade :)